# Is it a good practice to make different configuration files as symlinks to some scripts under the same directory?

Tags: configuration, bashrc, profile, pm-utils, bash-profile

I was wondering if it is a good practice to make the following configuration files as symlinks to some scripts under a directory e.g. `~/program_files/configurations/`.

- The scripts  `/etc/rc.local, /etc/profile, ~/.profile, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bashrc` are executed upon OS starting up, login shell starting up, and  interactive non-login shell starting up respectively.
- Scripts under `/usr/lib/pm-utils/sleep.d/` and `/etc/pm/sleep.d/` are executed upon OS suspension/hibernation and resuming/thawing.

My intention is that it will be easier to back up files in a directory than files in multiple directories.

Will using symlinks as configuration files create some unseen problems down the road?

Is it also a good idea to write a script to link the configuration files  under `~/program_files/configuration/` to where they will be used respectively?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite common actually especially with
[`dotfiles`](https://dotfiles.github.io/). The idea is that you keep
all your config files (hence `dotfiles` - conventionally they start
with `.`) in a single `git` repository. It allows for easy
synchronization between various machines and backup is provided for
free thanks to how `git` works. For example, on my machine:

```
$ ls -Alhtr ~/.bashrc
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ja users 21 Jun 22  2016 /home/ja/.bashrc -> dotfiles/bash/.bashrc
```

Comment: Thanks. Will using symlinks as configuration files create some unseen problems down the road?

Comment: I haven't had any problems with that. `Emacs` for example asks: `Symbolic link to Git-controlled source file; follow link? (y or n)` every time I open my `~/.bashrc`.